# i can't escape commas using weka explorer

Tags: csv, escaping, weka

i have a .csv file which contains some sentences like this :

> hi my name is Lorenzo, i want to solve this problem.

You can notice that there is a comma inside the sentence,i've tried putting it with

```
"," \, "\," ',' "'","'"
```

none of this worked...

the error that weka launch when i keep the sentence with comma is

> wrong number of values. Read 2, expected 1

Comment: Did you try enclosing the whole string in " like `"hi my name is Lorenzo, i want to solve this problem."` ?

Comment: yes, with excel trying to exclude other cases i put a single cell like this

"," the error is still there

Comment: also tryied with editpad

Comment: and the data are from sql server management studio, saving in csv format after the query

Comment: i notice that also the double apex " gave me error, even a string like 

"hi my name is lorenzo"
give me this error:
read 3 expecting 1

Comment: What is the header name (if any)?

Comment: no header, for now i eliminated all the characters that caused problem with weka but that's not what i was expecting to do.

Comment: i have a header but it is in the arff file derived from that csv

Comment: Can you give any link for the CSV file?